# C# TCPClient for quick request-response scenario

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, client, tcpclient

During my last task I've experienced a particular behaviour when receiving just after a send, in a TCPClient session, either in sync or async mode.

When I put a receive() just after having sent data to an echo server, the response is lost, especially when the echo server is on the same machine or in the same network. The problem seems to mitigate when the same experiment is set-up to pass through the Internet or when the echo-server answer is delayed.

I've also tried async model, just "using without touching" the MSDN related tutorial on asynchronous client socket programming. The code presented and linked below sends data, waits for send complete event and using a ManualResetEvent signals to the caller to go on through the Receive() function call. Data is lost also in this scenario.

The only way to capture data packet is to put the receive function call before the send one. While this is viable in async scenario, it becomes a problem in sync sockets.

My problem makes communication with a realtime TCP automation board way harder to manage, because my receive function goes off-sync by 1 call:

```
[t=1] send(get_status);
[t=2] receive(); //LOST with no data, execution goes on without exceptions
[t=3] send(get_status);
[t=4] receive(); //Got previous answer
```

I can assert that at t=4 the answer is the one expected from t=1 request because requests and subsequent responses are marked with a sequence identifier that has to be a monotonic increasing integer.

Putting Thread.Sleep() around seems to solve problems around but in no way I manage to solve my problems by sleeping over them.

How is this possible, considering the beautiful TCP theory? How this can be solved and brought to deterministic behaviour?

Thanks in advance for all your comments, proposals and solutions.

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong, but you are using a TCP server who receives and sends back any data? So in your code, you are trying to receive the data immediately after sending them? And a delay solves you problem? Seems like your server needs some time to receive and re-send the data... Maybe you should increase the receive timeout in your code then... at least for testing

Comment: Can we see what `receive` does, please?

Comment: @royalTS Common request-response scheme is:
Client asks: <command type="Status" Id="1"></command>
Server answers: <response type="Status" Id="1">XXXXXXXX</response>
But the problem arises also when I simply connect to myself on an echo server on the same machine, expecting the same response back.

For Fildor: the receive function is the socket.Receive() from TCPClient socket. The code is stripped down to Console.Writeline(whatever_comes_from_socket);

Comment: @PeppeA82 Then still the same tip from my side: Try to increase the timeout for receiving

Comment: @royalTS Thanks but timeout is set truly high (even 1000ms) and still nothing. It seems instead that response arrives BEFORE my code is ready to receive and process. Infact, if I delay my TCPEcho server response, everything works.

Comment: @PeppeA82 Are you closing the connection between sending and receiving? Otherwise, the data should be kept in the input buffer until you are ready to read them out, so, I do not believe that a response arriving before you are ready to read is the problem. Are you maybe reading before by accident?

Comment: @royalTS No, connection is always kept open. I have stripped down the code just to (sync mode)
`socket.send(data_to_be_sent);
var response = socket.receive(...)`
So I would exclude any read-before-write problem. The strange odd is that if I vary response time in echo server, delaying it, I perfectly receive data. It is like data arriving after my send() but before my receive().

Comment: @PeppeA82 But "data arriving after my send() but before my receive()" would be total normal